# Bootstrap Drop Down menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using bootstrap to create a drop down menu. However, I when I click Dropdown1, the contents of Dropdown1 cover the menu Dropdown2. What I want is, when I  click Dropdown1, its menu should be between Dropdown1 and Dropdown2 or Dropdown2 should be pushed downwards when the contents of Dropdown1 open.

This is the code I am applying;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>



      <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown1
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">python</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown2
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">perl</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position:static;
  float:none;
  width:150px;
}
```

See it working Here:

```css
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position:static;
  float:none;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
      
      <div class="dropdown clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown1
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">python</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown2
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">perl</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```